# React Passing function as parameter error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React-redux firestore for my application. I have a form, on submit ,passing the details to be saved and a function to execute success message if the firestore update is a success. receiving the following error 
'Error adding document:  TypeError: func is not a function'

Any help appreciated

submit function

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let uid = this.props.auth.uid;
        const { sp_License } = this.state;
        let err = this.validate();
        if (!err) {
          this.setState({ loading: true,disChecked:false })
          const Lfilename = this.state.sp_Name + '_' + new Date().getTime();
          const uploadTask = storage.ref('License/' + Lfilename).put(sp_License);
          uploadTask
            .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
              return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            })
            .then(url => {
              this.setState({ sp_License: url });
              const stateObj = this.state;
             this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, stateObj, this.successMessage)

            });
        }
    }

successMessage = () => {
        this.setState({
            message: 'Registration Successfull.!',
            open: true,
            loading: false,
        });
    };
```

Action Method

```
export const UpdateUserDetails= (id, droneSPDetails,func) => {
    console.log(droneSPDetails)
    console.log(func)
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore()
        firestore.collection('users')
            .doc(id)
            .set({
                 ...droneSPDetails,
                sp_RegisteredOn: new Date(),
                sp_Status:"pending",
                sp_ActiveFlag:"1",
            },{ merge: true })
            .then(() => {
                func();
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_DRONESP', droneSPDetails });

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `successMessage` being defined in relation to your `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: also, what does `console.log(func)` show you?

Comment: console.log(func) says undefined

Comment: `successMessage` is not string its function, calls setState()

Comment: Not sure, it looks ok. Try moving your whole successMessage function declaration in to the `.then` just before `this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, stateObj, this.successMessage)`

Comment: that works.. but i want to show message only on successfull save.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the scoping of `this`. I suggest you to maintain original reference, declare an extra variable at the beginning of your `handleSubmit()` to hold current `this`. Something like this:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {

        // maintain the reference
        const self = this


        e.preventDefault();
        let uid = this.props.auth.uid;
        const { sp_License } = this.state;
        let err = this.validate();
        if (!err) {
          this.setState({ loading: true,disChecked:false })
          const Lfilename = this.state.sp_Name + '_' + new Date().getTime();
          const uploadTask = storage.ref('License/' + Lfilename).put(sp_License);
          uploadTask
            .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
              return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            })
            .then(url => {

              this.setState({ sp_License: url });
              const stateObj = this.state;
              this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, stateObj, self.successMessage) // use original reference, `self` instead of `this`


            });
        }
    }
```